# Atom Startup: Project Home by Default

Tags: atom-editor

I would like to use the project home directory as the location of my current various projects:

Can I code the atom editor to startup by default in the project home directory?
Would this be very hard to implement for me as atom newbie, or is it doable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you define "project home"? Can't you have many projects?

Comment: @cricket_007: In "Settings" under "Core", there is an option to set a "Project Home" directory.

Comment: Okay, that isn't what you're looking looking for, then?

Comment: Like I would use it as a home directory where my current various projects are located.

Comment: That sounds like you just want to copyright folders into another folder on your hard drive. What's that have to do with Atom?

Comment: @cricket_007: No no, I don't want to link any folders/directories on my hard drive. I simply want to tell Atom to startup in a chosen directory by default.

Comment: I was under the impression that is what "Project Home" did. You can also chose to "always open empty editor". If those really are not working for you, you can edit the Atom editor shortcut to specify the directory after the binary, such as `atom /some/folder`